Failed to acquire connection/OLE DB provider is not registered only on SQL Server
I have an SSIS package that creates an Excel with a timestamp and exports table contents to said Excel. It runs fine in VS; and is virtually identical to another package I have that works fine both in VS and on the server after deployment.
But when I deploy this one and try to run via job agent it fails with the following 2 errors.

Create_Excel:Error: Failed to acquire connection "Excel Connection Manager". Connection may not be configured correctly or you may not have the right permissions on this connection.


Package:Error: The requested OLE DB provider Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0 is not registered. If the 64-bit driver is not installed, run the package in 32-bit mode. Error code: 0x00000000.
An OLE DB record is available.  Source: "Microsoft OLE DB Service Components"  Hresult: 0x80040154  Description: "Class not registered".

I had similar errors for the virtually identical package, but I was able to resolve those by exporting to Excel 97-2003, and setting
Run64BitRuntime = False

I have done the same for this package but am still getting the errors.
Could they be changing during deployment?
Possibly related
Upon opening the project in VS, I get several validation errors in the data flow task (after the SQL task where I create the excel that is failing in SQL Server). They do not prevent it from successfully running.
Also possibly related:
The working package has two connection managers when configured in SQL Server, where as the non working package only has one (it's missing the OLE DB connection to the server). I'm guessing this is due to the PackagePath in the connection manager properties being
Project.Connections 

in non working vs
Package.Connections 

in the working one.
I've no idea why they're different, how to change it, or if it's relevant.

Why are.you still using xls files and the JET driver? xlsx and ACE replaced those in 2007; it's 2024 now.

Because I was getting the noted 64 bit driver not installed errors.

There is no 64-bit JET driver, it doesn't exist, and never will. ACE, however, does have 64-bit drivers available.
